# flask Test Client throwing AttributeError when follow_redirects=True and werkzeug>=0.15

Tags: flask

using python 3.6, flask 0.12.4

fails when werkzeug>=0.15, runs fine on werkzeug==0.14.1

here is minimal code required to reproduce the error:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return redirect('/')

client = app.test_client()
client.get('/', follow_redirects=True)
```

here is the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 9, in <module>
    client.get('/', follow_redirects=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 1028, in get
    return self.open(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/testing.py", line 127, in open
    follow_redirects=follow_redirects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 1016, in open
    response, new_location, environ, buffered=buffered
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 947, in resolve_redirect
    return self.open(builder, as_tuple=True, buffered=buffered)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/testing.py", line 122, in open
    builder = make_test_environ_builder(self.application, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/testing.py", line 29, in make_test_environ_builder
    url = url_parse(path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/urls.py", line 457, in url_parse
    i = url.find(s(":"))
AttributeError: 'EnvironBuilder' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to upgrade Flask or downgrade Werkzeug. Werkzeug > 0.14 is not supported on Flask versions prior to 1.0

See: https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/3148

Comment: ok that worked thanks. hopefully upgrading flask will not break some other part of my code